# Many-to-many relationship within the same model Swift CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, many-to-many, relationship

I am trying to map a many to many relationship for Coredata in Swift. The problem is that the relationship is to the same object. Example: A Person object has a relation with many other Person objects as well as the inverse. Person A has a relation with Person B and Person C. Person B also has a relation with Person D as well as Person A.

Here is the code:

```
//Person.swift 
var id: Int = 0
var linkedPersonObjects: [PersonObject] = []
var linkedPeople: [Person] = []

required init(object: PersonObject) {

    self.id = Int(object.id)

    ...

    if let linkedPersonSet = object.linkedPeople where linkedPersonSet.count > 0 {
        guard let linkedPersonArray = linkedPersonSet.allObjects as? [PersonObject] else { return }
        for linkedPerson in linkedPersonArray {
            self.linkedPersonObjects.append(linkedPerson)
        }
    }

 }

 func update(oldPerson: PersonObject) -> PersonObject {

    oldPerson.populate(self)

    // Add linkedPeople
    let linkedSet = oldPerson.mutableSetValueForKey("linkedPeople")
    linkedSet.removeAllObjects()

    for linkedPerson in linkedPeople {
        linkedSet.addObject(linkedPerson.insertOrUpdate())
    }

    return oldPerson
}

func insert() -> PersonObject {

    assert(self.id == 0 || CoreDataUtils.findObjectWithId(Models.person, id: self.id) == nil, "ID \(self.id) already exists.")
    //creates and populates a new PersonObject
    let newPerson = PersonObject(person: self, context: context)

    //Adds contacts to linked contacts relationship
    let linkedSet = newPerson.mutableSetValueForKey("linkedPeople")
    for linkedPerson in linkedPeople {
        linkedSet.addObject(linkedPerson.insertOrUpdate())
    }

    return newContact

}
```

I thought I had something working, but every time I add Person B and Person C to Person A, then any relationships under Person B are no longer visible; however, Person A will properly have Person B and Person C.

I am not sure if I am going about this the right way or if there is something I am blanking on entirely.

Comment: It would help if you could post the details of your `Person` entity, being sure to include full details of the relationship(s) and their inverses.

Comment: Just added some code

Comment: I'm a little confused by the way the code includes both a `Person` class and a `PersonObject` class. How does `PersonObject` fit into the relationship of `Person` to itself?